# MacOS doesn't download the "Yelda 6.0.1" update

Tags: macos, updates, voice

I'm using "MacOS 10.12 Beta 2" and the App Store can not download the voice update. How can can I fix that?

[image: [Here's a screenshot](]

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar issues when trying to install XCode updates. I simply open my trusty Terminal and type `sudo softwareupdate -ia` to download and install all updates. If you want to install only a specific update, use the `--list`  option to see what updates are available then run

```
 sudo softwareupdate --install name_of_specific_update
```

Comment: I've been waiting for 6 hours but there's nothing to do. Still waiting.

`Tue Jul 19 10:23:10 EEST 2016
mac:~ mac$ sudo softwareupdate -ia
Software Update Tool
Copyright 2002-2015 Apple Inc.
Finding available software
Downloading Voice Update - Yelda`